# how to import .class library into project on Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, biometrics

I am working on a project creating a POS and I need to use a biometric reader, i found the SDK but the files of the library are in .class, is there any option like in Eclipse to import those files on Android Studio project? I only find the option of .JAR

[image: Screenshot of the files]

Comment: So can't you convert those .class files into a jar? Something like https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/toolsign/step2.html and then put that jar in some lib folder and  use  `api fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')`

Answer (score 0):

Copy your desired `.class` files in project structure.

```
project/Android/app/src/main/java/com/example/myapplication
```

`.class` files would be automatically decompiled in Android Studio. When you open those, you can see something similar like this:

```
// Source code recreated from a .class file by IntelliJ IDEA
// (powered by Fernflower decompiler)
```

Comment: But when i try to do the import doesnt find the library.

Comment: Don't import inside Android Studio. Copy and paste your `.class` files in project structure in `File Explorer`. Then open Android Studio. Your `.class` files would be decompiled automatically.

Comment: i can't do a import (import com.android.biomini.BioMiniAdnroid;) because doesnt read the classes. I can see the files decompiled but i cannot import then from a java class

Comment: Is your decompiled `.class` file is only readable? Try to write something in that file. Can you write something?